# Is there any way to add curly brace to new line on auto completion in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, curly-braces

I am comfortable using the following style

```
if (condition)
{
 //some code here
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's going to take you a pretty long and boring while...

The auto completion is simply a collection of *snippets*. You can extract the package that contains them (PHP or JavaScript, I don't know) and then edit them, one by one.

If you don't know what snippets are, I recommend you have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS_4yLizMBw) about them, you'll love them. (BTW, look every video of this playlist, it's pretty good)